# Do I have to free memory from every initialized string?

Tags: c, string, pointers

```
// loads a file into memory
void load_file()
{
   char *data = "This is so data";
   printf("function: %s\n", data);

}
```

Will the above code leak memory? Do I have call free(data)? Why or why not?

Comment: Rule of thumb: only `free` what you `malloc`ed.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel: Sweet so can I remove all my calls to `free` where I previously called `calloc` and `valloc` now? :)

Comment: @Joe Meh, when I wrote my comment I though "Oh, someone will go and nitpick the fact that I didn't mention the `malloc` variants... meh, probably not". Looks like I was wrong.

Comment: Apply the "as if by malloc" rule..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It cannot leak because you did not dynamically allocate it. `data` is a string literal and not a dynamically allocated array of characters.

Comment: Thanks. I think i get it now after your reply and searching literals etc. Basically, it goes into the .data section and you can only get memory leaks on things that go into the .bss section.

Comment: @user968102: you can only leak memory on the _heap_, the .bss is for uninitialized _data_.

Answer (score 1):

You don't allocate any memory there, so no memory is getting leaked. You are simply copying a pointer to an existing string in the executable image, not the string itself.

For that reason, the type of `data` should be `const char*` to prevent accidental changes to the string to which `data` points.

`data` itself, a pointer, is allocated on the stack, just like `i` in `int i = 5;` would be. That kind of implicit allocation is de-allocated automatically too.